# Neo4j default password (neo4j) is not working in community edition 3.2.0

Tags: amazon-ec2, neo4j

Installed community edition in AWS from https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B071P26C9D

Login credentials used:
username: neo4j
password: neo4j

Browser error:
Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized: The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.

I don't want to disable authentication "dbms.security.auth_enabled=false". Can anyone please help me to login or change the password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click on the "View Usage Instructions" under the Usage Information section, you should see this in there:

> The default password is your EC2 instance id.